# How to see contents of output queue of NIC in Linux and introspect frame delay

Tags: tc, packet-capture, queue, scheduling

I am experimenting with `tc` tool to implement prioritization of specific data coming from my computer and would like to see exatly how the frames are scheduled and how much time they spend **in the qdisc queue** before the transmission (before being dequeued). The goal is to make sure my `tc` configuration does what it is suposed to do.

Is there any tool that allows such introspection?

Comment: Suspiciously similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/261316/how-to-monitor-current-output-receive-queue-length-in-linux , there even are answers, but none accepted. Are you asking the same question?

Comment: Not exactly. I would like to look directly into the queue itself (if it is possible) to see what exact frames and in which order are scheduled for the transmission